# Extraction of NDVI values against each GPS coordinates of Landsat 8 images

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat-8

My goal is to calculate the NDVI value of each image from 2017 to 2022 but output values show the same value for each image.

Can you look at the code?

```
var Date_Start = ee.Date('2017-01-01');
var Date_End = ee.Date('2022-04-30');
//var Date_window = ee.Number(30);

// Create list of dates for time series
var n_months = Date_End.difference(Date_Start,'week').round();
print(n_months, "no. of weeks");
var dates = ee.List.sequence(2,n_months,2);
print(dates, "week list");
var make_datelist = function(n) {
  return Date_Start.advance(n,'week');
};
dates = dates.map(make_datelist);
print(dates,"dates");

var fnc = function(d1) {
  var date = ee.Date(d1).format("YYYY-MM-dd");
  var start = ee.Date(d1);
  var end = ee.Date(d1).advance(5,'day');
  var date_range = ee.DateRange(start,end);
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA');
var image = ee.Image(
  l8.filterBounds(point)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first()
);

  return l8.mosaic().normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).clip(GG);
};

var list_of_images = dates.map(fnc);
print('list_of_images', list_of_images);
var ndviCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(list_of_images);
 
var NDVImean = ndviCol.mean();
var NDVIsd = ndviCol.reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev());
var NDVIcv = NDVIsd.divide(NDVImean); 


Map.addLayer(NDVIsd, null, 'NDVIsd');

print(ndviCol);
var ndviMultiTemp = ndviCol.toBands();
print(ndviMultiTemp);
Map.centerObject(GG, 7);


Map.addLayer(ndviCol.first(), {min:-1, max:1}, 'NDVI');
// EXPORT Tools

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndviMultiTemp.clip(GG),
  description: 'B2B3NDVIsd', 
  //region: GG.geometry(),
  scale: 30,
 // maxPixels:le13,
  skipEmptyTiles: true
  });
  // Extract data for each point
var sample = ndviMultiTemp
      .sampleRegions({
        // Get the sample from the points FeatureCollection.
        collection: point,
        // Properties from the points collection to pass on to the sampled info
        //properties: ['id'],
        // Set the scale to get Sentinel pixels in the FeatureCollection.
        scale: 30,
        tileScale: 8,
        // Return geometries
        geometries: true
      });

// Transform coordinates into properties in the table.
var FeaturetoPro = sample.map(function (feature) {
  // Get geometry
  var coordinates = feature.geometry()
                          // Transform it to the desired EPSG code. Here WGS 84
                          .transform('epsg:4326')
                          // Get coordinates as a list
                          .coordinates();
  // Get both entries of coordinates and set them as new properties
  var result = feature.set('lon', coordinates.get(0), 
                     'lat', coordinates.get(1));
  // Remove geometry                   
  return result.setGeometry(null);
});

// Export table as csv
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: FeaturetoPro,
    description: 'Bands Vaue with coord',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I think this should be done using the filtered `imageCollection`.
And I found a new problem that there are null image that I cannot calculate NDVI.

Comment: Please post the code as text : https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: I'm confused as to whether you are trying to ask an unmarked question within your answer.  If so, please do that as a new question.